# DATA COM VALOR NUMERICO

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, microsoft-excel

Realizo a importação de um planilha onde existem varios campos de data que são o foco da minha importação, só que quando é importada para o banco de dados ela vai em valor númerico, existe alguma forma de converter esses valores de volta em data ou em uma string com o valor correto para dessas datas? pois preciso fazer comparação se os vendendores informaram datas incorretas como sábado, domingo ou feriados e apos essas analise preciso jogar dias a frente para sair dessas datas incorretas!

Imagem para análise:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem apos a importação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu consigo trabalhar com esses valores após a importação com algum método date() do php?

Já procurei muito e não encontrei uma forma de configurar os dados no excel antes da importação, até mudei os formatos dos campos no MySQL para string achando que ele iria reconhecer as datas em texto, mas sem sucesso.

Utilizo o Framework Laravel e a biblioteca Laravel Excel para a importação

Comment: Este valor é o dia juliano, isto é o número de dias decorridos desde 30/12/1899 (conforme utilizado pelo Excel e similares para representar uma data). Uma possível maneira de trabalhar com esse número é converte-lo para o `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` reconhecido pelo MySQL, subtraia 25569 e multiplique o resultado por 24*60*60 que obterá a quantidade de segundos decorridos desde 01/01/1970. Ou converta este número numa string contendo a data gregoriana e daí importe para seu banco de dados.

Comment: Outra possibilidade é criar uma coluna auxiliar no Excel contendo a fórmula `=TEXTO(célula_contendo_data;"dd/mm/aaaa")` que gerará uma string com a data correspondente.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a biblioteca https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet, ela possui um recurso para esse tipo de caso, eu mesmo precisei resolver esse problema:

1. Primeiro precisa importar a classe Date dessa biblioteca:

`use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date;`

2. Depois, basta usar, como por exemplo, eu havia feito uma validação também:

```
  if(is_numeric($data)) {
    $dataConvertida = Date::excelToDateTimeObject($data)->format('Y-m-d');
  }
```